# CSS selector: element without any its children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a nested unordered list with one "li" element defined with identifier: [data-main]

> - 1 (must be selected)
>
>   - 1.1
>   - 1.2
> - 2

using the following html:

```
<ul>
  <li data-main>1 (must be selected)
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to find the right CSS selector for selecting only element 1 without its children: 1.1 and 1.2. Selectors, I tried:

`li:not([data-main])` - selects all li except main, but i need something opposite

`[data-main]:not(:nth-child(1))` - selects nothing

https://jsfiddle.net/DaViking/dtqhag2t/

Comment: What do you think the direct opposite of `:not([data-main])` is?

Comment: @Panda: The `[data-main]` selector is *not selecting the children* but the border is *covering the children* because, well, the children are part of the parent.

Comment: Harry is right, you could propably solve this by adding a div or span around the text in the li, so you only select the text, and not the whole list element. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dtqhag2t/1/

Comment: Thank you Matthias, but the goal was not to add something, because this list is creating in contenteditable div. James proposed the solution to exclude the styling for others elements.

Comment: @Panda if James has answered your question, tick the checkbox by his answer.

Comment: Symlink, sure i do. But I had to wait 7 minutes before checkbox will be active.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're not realising is that the `[data-main]` selector in your JSFiddle demo *is* selecting only that top-level `li` element. The problem you're facing here is that this `li` element *contains* the other `li` elements. Those aren't selected by this selector individually, but they are contained within the element which is selected:

[image: Example]

If you want to style just the text held within the `[data-main]` element but *not* within the `ul` element contained within it, you'll need to override the `[data-main]` style declarations:

```css
[data-main] {
  color: red;
}

[data-main] ul {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-main>1 (must be selected)
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to place a border around the "1 (must be selected)" text and nothing else, you can wrap that text in a `span` element and apply styling to that instead:

```css
[data-main] span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-main>
    <span>1 (must be selected)</span>
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't see this as i was writing my answer - apologies! Removed mine now.

Comment: With solution, you proposed, I would like to precise the limitation of styling: I can play only with some text css properties: color, font-size... isn't it?

Comment: @Panda there's not really any limitation if you are able to modify the HTML to add that `span` element in.

Comment: I'm talking about the first solution you proposed.

Comment: @Panda well anything not on the block-level (that wraps the entire container) can be overwritten on the children (which is mostly just background (depending on padding/margin), text styling and margin (only if you introduce negative margin to counter the container margin)).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, i added `background-color: lightcyan;` on the `[data-main]` and override color for the children. But the color hasn't overrided: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtqhag2t/3/). What I forgot?

Comment: @Panda the `initial` background colour on those is `transparent`, meaning it wouldn't visually override anything. You can instead set it to `white`, or whatever the background of your page is: https://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/dtqhag2t/4/